# What is the title of this Star Wars book?

Tags: story-identification, star-wars

I remember reading a book as a teen where there was a reptilian race that appears after the timeline of *Return of the Jedi*.

It was an "official" Star Wars book, branded as such from the book store at the time.

I vaguely remember it had something to do with a Jedi taken very young who was brainwashed by this reptilian race and used as a tool for their gain. Luke Skywalker was definitely a part of the story as well as a main protagonist.

Comment: @kitgui.com here's the [timeline](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline_of_books) of all the books released.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The book sounds like it could be *The Truce at Bakura* by Kathy Tyers. Wookieepedia quotes the publisher's [blurb](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Truce_at_Bakura):

> No sooner has Darth Vader's funeral pyre burned to ashes on Endor than the Alliance faces a new challenge at the far-flung Imperial outpost of Bakura. The Ssi-Ruuk, a race of cold-blooded reptilian invaders, plan to enslave human minds to pilot their invincible machines of war and destruction. With the hope of turning Bakura's loyalties toward the fledgling New Republic with defensive aid, Luke Skywalker, Han Solo, and Princess Leia race to the besieged planet. Yet as the eve of the final onslaught rapidly approaches, Rebel and Imperial forces still must come to terms with each other. And there is already evidence of a traitor hidden in their midst…

Woookieeepedia's [synopsis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Truce_at_Bakura#Synopsis) has much more detail.

I suspect it won't be the basis for Episode 7, though (unless young Ssi-Ruuk are as cute and merchandisable as Ewoks).

Comment: I do remember that title now that you mention it. The title is pretty lame for a 7th movie. I agree that its unlikely they will use this but I would like to know a possible interesting story they could use as I didn't follow it past that book.

Comment: It probably wouldn't be it, but the Thrawn Trilogy, by Timothy Zahn, are often viewed as some of the best Star Wars novels written. It starts with Heir to the Empire.

Comment: When I was a kid in High School, Star Wars novels were just beginning to be written.  I think this was the fourth book to be written, after a trilogy was written by Timothy Zahn, I believe.  Any way, I read about 10 of those early novels and this was a book I could not read.  I recall it was quite a snoozer to a 14 year old.

Comment: @RLH it was a total bore. You are right. I was hoping this is not part of the 7th movie Disney releases.